# SQL Count Expressions

Tags: sql, count, sas

I am trying to create a table to will count the occurrences of each position for various offices.

So if my data is as follows:

```
Office Position
A      Manager
A      Supervisor
A      Entry Level
A      Entry Level
B      Manager
B      Entry Level
```

I would want my code to return:

```
Office    Managers    Supervisors     EntryLevel
A            1             1              2
B            1             0              1
```

I have my code below. The issue is that this code counts the total amount of occurrences, not the unique count to each office. The results are as follows

```
A   2   1   3
B   2   1   3

CREATE TABLE OfficeTest AS
SELECT DISTINCT Office,
(Select COUNT(Position) FROM OfficeData  WHERE Make_Name = 'Manager') as Managers, 
(Select COUNT(Position) FROM OfficeData  WHERE Make_Name = 'Supervisor') as Supervisors,
(Select COUNT(Position) FROM OfficeData  WHERE Make_Name = 'Entry Level') as EntryLevel

FROM OfficeData 
GROUP BY Office;
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What SQL database *product* are you using? (e.g. SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc). For any product that supports it, this is practically a quintessential use for `PIVOT`.

Comment: I am using the Proc SQL function in SAS. The count case below is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: If you're using SAS, why not use a SAS summarization procedure, like `PROC TABULATE`?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I can think of doing this is like this:

```
SELECT Office,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Make_Name = 'Manager' THEN Position END) AS Managers,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Make_Name = 'Supervisor' THEN Position END) AS Supervisors,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Make_Name = 'Entry Level' THEN Position END) AS EntryLevel
FROM OfficeData
GROUP BY Office
```

`COUNT` ignores `MISSING` values; if the `Position` is not the one specified in the `CASE` clause, it will return a `MISSING` value and won't be counted. This way each case considers only the value of `Position` you compare.

Another option, as stated in the comments, would be pivoting the table. The SAS equivalent is the `TRANSPOSE` procedure. I don't have a SAS system to create and test a query using it, but [here's the documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#transpose-overview.htm) in case you want to check it out.

Comment: It's maybe just personal preference, but I generally do a SUM rather than COUNT and have the CASE return 1 or 0, depending on whether Make_Name matches the value for that column.  I think the logic is more self-evident.

Comment: Now that you mention it, it would be interesting to write it both ways and see execution plans.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks. I am using SAS so the Else Null portion doesn't work I don't think that affects me.

Comment: I edited the answer. Didn't know SAS doesn't have `NULL` but `MISSING` values instead. Yet, technically the `ELSE NULL/MISSING` part isn't needed as, if no `CASE` condition is met, a `MISSING` is returned by default.

Comment: I personally prefer `count`; perhaps that's because of my math background. I tend to be explicit about the `else` just to be clear and so it doesn't even save any characters. I've thought about having the case expression evaluate to something like `'CountMe'` instead of a number. In the end I think it's all straightforward to anybody competent.

Answer (score 1):

Just to flush out Danny's comment a bit, the SUM code would look like:

```
proc sql;
    CREATE TABLE want AS
    SELECT office,
    SUM( (position='Manager') ) as Managers,
    SUM( (position='Supervisor') ) as Supervisors,
    SUM( (position='Entry Level') ) as EntryLevel
FROM OfficeData
GROUP BY office
;quit;
```

The `(position='Manager')` bit resolves to 0 or 1, depending on if its true for the current record. I find the SUM version a lot more concise and legible, but both should work for your situation. Plus, its easily extensible to more than one criteria, like `(postion='Manager')*(sex='F')` to count only female managers.

Answer (score 0):

SUM with CASE statement should resolve the issue. Below is a reference code

```
proc sql;
create table result as 
select age
      , sum(case sex when 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as Female
      , sum(case sex when 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as Male
from sashelp.class
group by age;
quit;
proc print data=result;run;
```